# How to measure and collect loading speed data of a website across the globe?

Tags: performance, analytics

I have used tools such as YSlow to measure the loading speed of our website. Since I am located in Germany, our customers however are mostly in Asia (and our server in the US), I would like to measure the 'real' loading speed on the customer side.

Anyone has a hint on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo's Boomerang is not an 'out-of-the-box' solution, but could provide the framework to do exactly what you're looking for. http://yahoo.github.com/boomerang/doc/

If anyone finds anything simpler, please let us know!